# Как подставить переменную в SQLite запрос?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt5, sqlite3

Здравствуйте. Не подскажите ли, как можно подставить переменную в нижеприведенный запрос? Что-то наподобие этого:

```
int deleteId = 15;

query.exec("DELETE FROM datatree WHERE rowid = deleteId");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int deleteId = 15;
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("DELETE FROM datatree WHERE rowid = :deleteId");
query.bindValue(":deleteId", deleteId );
query.exec();
```

Смотрите документацию по [QSqlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html), там всё есть.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё можно воспользоваться функционалом `QString`:

```
int deleteId = 15;
query.exec(QString("DELETE FROM datatree WHERE rowid = %1").arg(deleteId));
```

Comment: Ни в коем случае. **НИКОГДА** так не делайте. Почему? Читайте, что такое SQL Injection.

Comment: @ixSci, разве аналогичный SQL-injection не возможен при вызове `bindValue` ?

Comment: Нет, `bindValue` для этого и сделан, чтобы исключить эту атаку

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо, буду знать. В документации не нашёл прямого упоминания о том, что `bindValue` строго гарантирует невозможность SQL-injection. Если не сложно, поделитесь ссылкой.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement , а в самой документации уже видим *«QSqlQuery supports prepared query execution and the binding of parameter values to placeholders.»*

Comment: @ixSci, прекрасно. Век живи - век учись. Благодарю!